# Manual authentication throw CustomAuthenticationProvider (Spring MVC)

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I try to manual login with username and password with Spring MVC

I have CustomSessionAuthenticationProvider:

```
  public class CustomSessionAuthenticationStrategy implements AuthenticationProvider {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) {
        String username = authentication.getName();
        String password = (String) authentication.getCredentials();

        User user = userService.loadUserByUsername(username);

        if (user == null) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Username not found.");
        }

        if (!password.equals(user.getPassword())) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Wrong password.");
        }

        Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities = user.getAuthorities();

        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, password, authorities);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> arg0) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

I included it in Security Config :

```
 @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }
```

I don't understand how manually authenticate, if i have in controller username and password and get sessionId and token from it.

Method authenticate in input need authentication, but i need login and password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need a controller for manual authentication, spring security registers a controller at /login for the post method automatically and does the authentication for you, if you have configured it correctly. Please have a look at this blog post for an example or the spring security manual: http://kielczewski.eu/2014/12/spring-boot-security-application/

Comment: i've tried to configure spring security with you manual, but have some questions. I've created new post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31802641/spring-security-accessing-rest-api